# Redirect www to non www godaddy with nginx

Tags: nginx, devops

I have a website with non www url , i tried to redirect it using following steps -

For DNS i have used go daddy where

```
Type           name         value           ttl     
  A              @        xx.xx.xx.xx       600 seconds
CNAME           www            @             1 Hour
```

In my Nginx configuraion i made following changes -

```
server {
listen 443;     
server_name  XAXA.com www.XAXA.com;
if ($host = XAXA.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} 
 return 404;
}
```

I am able to login my site with XAXA.com but whenever i try with www.XAXA.com i get - Your connection is not private

I am using let's encrypt for SSl.

Answer (score 0):

The "connection is not private" warning is related to the certificate you present. Your browser is unable to verify that the certificate presented by the server is valid for www.xaxa.com

Without knowing the exact contents of your certificate I guess that your certificate doesn't have the proper `Subject Alternative Name` set up.

I'll be using [`openssl`](https://www.openssl.org/) as an example of how to view contents of a certificate but you can use whatever you want.

I assume your certificate's `Subject` looks something like this

```
$ openssl s_client -connect xaxa.com:443 -showcerts | openssl x509 -subject -noout
CN = xaxa.com
```

This is fine and doesn't need to be changed. Depending on your browser it may not even be part of the validation process when verifying the certificate against the host.

I also assume your certificate's `Subject Alternative Name` looks something like this

```
$ openssl s_client -connect xaxa.com:443 -showcerts 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text -noout 2>/dev/null | grep -A 1 'Subject Alternative Name'
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
  DNS:xaxa.com
```

What you want to achieve is a list in that `Subject Alternative Name` field:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect xaxa.com:443 -showcerts 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text -noout 2>/dev/null | grep -A 1 'Subject Alternative Name'
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
  DNS:xaxa.com, DNS:www.xaxa.com
```

If you have several subdomains you could supply a wildcard value instead of `www`, ie. `DNS:*.xaxa.com`

How you actually achieve that with regards to Let's Encrypt depends on which [ACME client implementation](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/) you're using.